# Executing a specific macro in emacs evil

Tags: emacs, macros, elisp, evil-mode

Right now I am trying to use the evil plugin in emacs so that I can have the editing capability of vim with the extensibility of emacs. Right now I'm trying to port over one of my favorite parts of my .vimrc: have space repeat whatever my last executed macro was. In my .vimrc it was simply

```
nore <Space> @@
```

I am trying to do the same thing in my .emacs file with

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map " " (lambda () (interactive) (evil-execute-macro 1 "@")))
```

@@ repeats the last macro fine, however hitting space gives me the error

```
After 0 kbd macro iterations: No previous macro
```

I'm fairly new to lisp and evil so I'm sure I'm doing something very wrong and I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind it similarly to vim:

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map " " (kbd "@@"))
```

Regarding your code: The second argument of `evil-execute-macro` should be a character, i.e. `?@`. But this only holds if `evil-execute-macro` is called interactively because the content of the corresponding register is only retrieved in the `interactive` form.

This boils down to this: The correct call would be `(evil-execute-macro 1 last-kbd-macro)`.